# How to locate exact store locations on Google by searching my website using "near me" keywords, considering I have multiple stores in various cities?

Tags: seo, google-local-search

How can I optimize my website for SEO to ensure that customers searching for our store products using the "near me" keyword on Google can easily find the exact store location with the desired products?

I've tried incorporating product and location keywords like "Redmi 12 Note near me" in Google search, but it seems that the "near me" functionality with specific product names is not producing the desired results.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as the SEO tag states: GENERAL SEO QUESTIONS ARE OFF-TOPIC. Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on Webmasters.SE at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com. Please delete your question here first.

Answer (score 0):

The search engine results page (SERP) for the query "near me" is based on localization, including geo data.
Detailed localization of your stores, including address and geo identifiers, can help you, e.g., **[Thesaurus of Geographic Names](https://vocab.getty.edu/tgn/)** and/or **[GeoNames](https://www.geonames.org/)**. Relevant structured data representing the localization of your stores also can help. You can also indicate the localization of your stores in your business profile panel.